# Not able to declare a shell variable in a ssh session correctly

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to create a directory on my remote server with the current timestamp. For which I need the following code to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ssh -l pi something.com -p 8888 << EOF
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP=`date +%s`
  echo "creating directory with timestamp $CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
EOF
```

But when I see the output of the echo command the `$CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value is completely missing. If I ssh into the remote machine and run each command one by one, everything works as expected.

Comment: just wondering. What's a point to run the `sshd` on port 8888?

Comment: please ignore, port 8888 was not put on purpose, sorry about the distraction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
ssh -l pi something.com -p 8888 << "EOF"
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP=`date +%s`
  echo "creating directory with timestamp $CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
EOF
```

and have a look at `man -P'less +/<<' bash`

> ... If any  characters  in  word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.  If  word is  unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion...